# SQL Understanding Table Unique Constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I spent the day trying to debug an issue only now I see what the problem has been all along. I have a unique constraint on my table that forces only unique values as Catalog number. I, however do not seem to have a good understanding of what would constitute unique in this case. I have two product numbers **MP1156** and **MP1156ZF**.

```
Insert into IDWProductCodes( PRCEAN, PRCGTIN, PRCatalogNumber, PRCIsActive, PRIsReplaced, PrIsREPlacement,PRProductID)
   Select 
      '11232', '23223', 'MP115BP', 1, 0, 0, '267F104C-6BA4-4C7E-A0C1-6615CBB9DA4C'

Insert into IDWProductCodes( PRCEAN, PRCGTIN, PRCatalogNumber, PRCIsActive, PRIsReplaced, PrIsREPlacement,PRProductID)
   Select 
      '11232', '23223', 'MP115', 1, 0, 1, '267F104C-6BA4-4C7E-A0C1-6615CBB9DA4C'

Insert into IDWProductCodes( PRCEAN, PRCGTIN, PRCatalogNumber, PRCIsActive, PRIsReplaced, PrIsREPlacement,PRProductID)
   Select
      '11232', '23223', 'MP15', 1, 1, 1, '267F104C-6BA4-4C7E-A0C1-6615CBB9DA4C'
```

I get an error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 5
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_CNUMUNIQUE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.IDWProductCodes'. The duplicate key value is (MP115).

What has been happening is each time I insert the first key and then try to insert the second key, SQL assumes they are the same and overwrites the first with the second, an effect I don't want at all.

What I really want is the ability to enter different strings(no duplicates) in the table. I had thought a unique constraint was all it would take but now i am not sure. What is the better or best approach to solving this problem please?

Comment: What is the width and type on the Product Number column? Also, can you script out the unique constraint you are talking about and include it in your question?

Comment: If you'd show us your schema, it would be easier to help you. The strings 'MP1156' and 'MP11156ZF' don't collate as equal. SQL compares string by effectively padding the shorter to the length of the longer with blanks and working left-to-right, comparing each character in turn: the first difference determines the result.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey, I am trying to understand SQL could conclude MP1156 are not unique MP1156ZF

Comment: Are you sure your code is inserting what you think it is? Try temporarily removing the constraint and run the code and see if you really are inserting the values you think you are.

Comment: These are simple insert statements giving me the error above.

Comment: Can you script out the table, any indexes, and any triggers on that table?

Comment: ALTER TABLE IDWProductCodes ADD CONSTRAINT UK_UniqueCatalogNum UNIQUE (PRCatalogNumber)

Comment: The UNIQUE key name in the ALTER TABLE statement you just posted is not the same as the name of the key being violated in the error message in the question.  Is that a mistake, or is there another key floating around?

Comment: This is pretty basic, but are you remembering to remove all existing data before running those INSERT statements?  If there was *already* a record in the table with 'MP115' before the first INSERT, the second one would bomb out with just that message.

Comment: The table was empty to begin with. I think the problem has to do with a relationship from the table to another table. That is what I can think of as the issue.

Comment: Did you try removing the relationship to see if the error goes away? That would at least enable you to isolate the source of the problem for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting what is going on. A SQL Unique constraint is not going to cause an overwrite of the existing row if you try to insert a duplicate. The second insert that violates the constraint will fail.

Please show the code you are using for the inserts and the table structure. I will modify this answer to address the real issue after I see that, but from the information you have provided the unique constraint is not the problem.

Also, make sure you don't have a TRIGGER on that table. That is the only thing that I can think of that would create such wonky behavior as an insert replacing an existing row.

Comment: You are right that a unique constraint should not cause an overwrite,however, while searching for why a previous insert would be overwritten. I decided to do direct inserts to the table using the values that I believe were at the root of the problem, and got the error above indicating the constraint was not happy about what I was doing.

Comment: How do I ensure that strings like MP115BP and MP115 are not considered same in my constraint?

Comment: And no, I don't have any triggers on my table. I just dropped the constraint, ran the insert fine, and then tried to put back the constraint and got similar error message --- The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.IDWProductCodes' and the index name 'UK_UniqueCatalogNum'. The duplicate key value is (MP115).

Answer (score 0):

Something else is going on.  SQL Server will not confuse the two strings 'MP115' and 'MP115BP' as the same value.  You have been asked several times to script out the table structure so that we can see it.  You do this use SSMS, right-clicking on the table, and ***Script Table As > CREATE to > Clipboard***.  If you post the results of that we may be able to help more.

Here's a wild guess, however.  Is it possible that you have a computer column in the table that truncates PRCatalogNumber to 5 characters and itself has a different UNIQUE INDEX on it?  That would cause the problem you're seeing.